# How can I navigate to an Active Directory object in the domain tree?

Tags: active-directory

In the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in in MMC I can find groups or users fairly simply and view their details. But how can I navigate to that object in the domain tree?

I haven't found any ways to navigate directly from search results or an object, but I also don't see any information relating to "parent" OUs in the displayed object.

Is there a way to navigate to the object in the tree in this snap-in? Or is the only way to run a `dsquery` command to retrieve the full including all OUs, then drill down manually?

Comment: To see information relating to "parent" OUs in the displayed object:  
in the upper menu of a search windows select View -> Choose columns -> Published At -> Add -> OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `Advanced Features` to view object details like the CN of an object which is the "OU-path" you can follow to find it in domain tree:

[image]

Information like this can be found in the ribbon `Object`.

As far as I know there is no "one-klick" feature to jump to the position in the domain tree.

Comment: To clarify since it wasn't immediately obvious to me: enabling Advanced Features adds several tabs to an object's Properties view, including the Object tab which indeed contains the full CN (meaning all parent OUs).